# SSL_Accept fails with error:FFFFFFFF:lib(255):func(4095):reason(4095)

Tags: ssl, openssl

I am trying a write a openssl server and SSL_Accept fails with error:FFFFFFFF:lib(255):func(4095):reason(4095). What this error code means? How can i get the  description of openssl error codes?

Answer (score 0):

> and SSL_Accept fails with error:FFFFFFFF

0xFFFFFFFF is -1. You should call `SSL_get_error` next. From [`SSL_accept(3)`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_accept.html):

> If the underlying BIO is blocking, SSL_accept() will only return once
>   the handshake has been finished or an error occurred, except for SGC
>   (Server Gated Cryptography). For SGC, SSL_accept() may return with -1,
>   but SSL_get_error() will yield SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ/WRITE and
>   SSL_accept() should be called again.
>
> If the underlying BIO is non-blocking, SSL_accept() will also return
>   when the underlying BIO could not satisfy the needs of SSL_accept() to
>   continue the handshake, indicating the problem by the return value -1.
>   In this case a call to SSL_get_error() with the return value of
>   SSL_accept() will yield SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ or SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE.
>   The calling process then must repeat the call after taking appropriate
>   action to satisfy the needs of SSL_accept().